# How do I verify SSL connection with a server through bash?

Tags: bash, ssl

I have a server where certificates are installed. The hostname of server is abc.example.com. The certificates installed on server has different DNS name in CN (def.example.com). However, the certificate has SubjAltNames which specifies both abc.example.com and def.example.com. This server runs a Tomcat server and has keystore properly configured. The client has the necessary RootCA installed. I want to verify through bash script that if a connection attempt to the server succeeds in this scenario. I tried using following command -

```
`wget --server-response --max-redirect=0 https://abc.example.com:443/myapp`
```

However, both the command fails with 
ERROR: certificate common name `def.example.com` doesn't match requested host name `abc.example.com`.

Any inputs on how can I verify that the root-ca installed on client is indeed usable to connect to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `openssl s_client` SSL client, which is intended for SSL debugging and has a large number of relevant command line flags (which you can probably read about by typing `man s_client`, but that's somewhat distro-specific). In particular, look at the `-verify` and `-showcerts` options.